# Problems with dots in the end of tags

Tags: php, wordpress

I am struggling with this piece of code.  I do not want a dot after the last tag, what line do I write so that there is no dot after the last tag?

```
<?php
    $id = get_sub_field('case_link');
    $posttags = get_the_tags($id);
    $tags = '';

    if ($posttags) {
        foreach ($posttags as $tag) {
            $tags .= $tag->name . ' &middot; ';
        }
    }

    $tags = trim(substr($tags, 0, -2));
?>
```

Comment: Where did you get this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a counter and check if you are on the last iteration, if so add the name without the dot.

```
$id = get_sub_field('case_link');
$posttags = get_the_tags($id);
$tags = '';
$i = 0;
$len = count($posttags);

foreach ($posttags as $tag) {
    if($i != $len-1) {
        $tags .= $tag->name . ' &middot; ';
    }
    else {
        $tags .= $tag->name;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [rTrim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) function

```
rtrim($yourString, 'ChartoRemove');
```

For your case

```
rtrim($tags, '&middot;');
```